# Javascript: regex to replace some characters with their hexadecimal code

Tags: javascript, regex, url-encoding

I haven't been able to find an example that does something similar to what I want, that is, replace:

% with %25

& with %26

/ with %2F

# with %23

" with space

\ with space

For the reference I'm using GWT with String.replaceAll, but I'm asking about Javascript since that is what it gets translated to anyway. I know about (component) URI encoding, but it's not what I'm after, I only need these characters.

Later edit: I'm looking for a way to do it in one or two regexes, right now it's done as this:

`splits[i].replaceAll("%", "%25").replaceAll("&", "%26").replaceAll("/","%2F").replaceAll("#", "%23").replaceAll("\"", "").replaceAll("\\\\", " ");`

but this seems ugly to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(This is for JavaScript, which is the language you asked about. Note that it will be fairly different in Java.)

In JavaScript, this is trivial using [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a regular expression and [passing in a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter):

```
var str = "testing % & / # \" \\";
var result = str.replace(/[%&\/#"\\]/g, function(m) {
    return (m === '"' || m === '\\') ? " " : "%" + m.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/eruheg) | [source](http://jsbin.com/eruheg/edit)

If you don't mind scanning the string twice rather than once, it can look a *bit* simpler (though not enough that I think it's worth it):

```
var str = "testing % & / # \" \\";
var result = str.replace(/["\\]/g, " ").replace(/[%&\/#]/g, function(m) {
    return "%" + m.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
});
```

...because we can do the `"` and `\` replacement separately and get rid of the check for what we matched. [Live example](http://jsbin.com/eruheg/2) | [source](http://jsbin.com/eruheg/2/edit)

Comment: Great answer, I will wait a bit and mark it as the solution; even though it's not really doable in my app it solves the question elegantly. I was looking to see if there was a way to do it with a generic/standard regular expression with capture->replace.

Comment: @brainwash: *"I was looking to see if there was a way to do it with a generic/standard regular expression with capture->replace..."* Not in JavaScript; you can move things around using capture groups and placeholders (for instance, `"testing".replace(/(t)(.)/g, "$2$1")` => `"etsitng"`), but to do *transformations*, you have to use a function. I'm not familiar with any regex engine that would let you convert characters to their character codes without having it call back to a function you write (but then most of my experience with regex is in JavaScript) or, of course, doing them individually.

Answer (score 0):

```
String.replace(/%/, '%25').replace(/&/, '%26').replace(/\//, '%2F').replace(/#/, '%23').replace(/"/, ' ').replace(/\\/, ' ');
```

Comment: That's exactly what I do now, but I was looking if there was a way to do it in one or maybe two steps.

Comment: Several problems with the above: 1. There is no `String.replace` function, `replace` is a function on string *instances* (inherited from `String.prototype`), not the `String` constructor function. 2. This scans the string repeatedly. 3. This will only replace the *first* occurrence of each character, not all of them.